# SXA: Rows and columns disappearing

Tags: sxa

Using SXA 1.2 rev. 161216, rows and columns sometimes disapear from pages.

By this I mean that the Row Splitter component **still exists** and its content is still visible in the **design layout** menu.

When I add a row using the **+** button to the corrupted row splitter, the hidden row that was here before **comes back**. Video : https://www.screencast.com/t/XDHSMXTje

This is very annoying since this breaks our work. Does anyone have a solution to this ?

Comment: Such issues was registered in our backlog long time ago and it's already fixed. I strongly recommend to upgrade to 1.4 version.

Comment: I too experienced this issue. Reference 7147 to get the fix from Sitecore Support.

Answer (score 1):

While working with SXA 1.3 we too noticed an issue with the row splitter; since corrected with SXA 1.4.

As part of my support ticket (7147) to Sitecore, I indicated that whenever I add a 3rd+ row, the new row appears 50% width.

[image: Busted Row]

Further inspection revealed the component contained column properies, which it should not. Manually removing them corrected the issue for that one row.

[image: Extra Properties]

Using the patch by Sitecore has worked for us just fine.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've removed my answer. Also note that @Dawid Rutkowski has confirmed this is fixed in SXA 1.4.

Comment: It is not exactly the same issue. In my case, everything works fine when building rows but then they disappear. I'm joining a video that shows what happens when I put back the row https://www.screencast.com/t/XDHSMXTje